# How do you filter on property names when you merge two objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, object, merge, lodash

I'm trying to merge two object using lodash and performing a filter on property names based on source property criteria but the source property name is mangles  in the result. Filter doesn't seem to work on object property names.

```
result = _.merge(library, 
  _.filter(inbasket, function(book) {
    return parseFloat(book.rating) > 3.9;
  })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shirha/d1j1yq4w/

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to preserve the property names in the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `_.filter` use [`_.pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pickBy) for object

```
result = _.merge(
    library, 
    _.pickBy(inbasket, function(book) {
        return parseFloat(book.rating) > 3.9;
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a lodash solution.

Answer (score 1):

When _.filter is used on an object, the returned value is an array. So you are trying to merge an array into an object. The array is also technically an object, but the keys are 0, 1, 2... so you can still merge the array with the object, but the original keys will be lost. This is what results from your _.filter operation:

```
[  {
     name: "HTML5 Hacks",
     pub: "OReilly",
     year: 2012,
     rating: "4.5"
   },
   {
     name: "Pro Django 2e",
     pub: "Apress",
     year: 2013,
     rating: "4.0"
   }
]
```

Here's a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/d1j1yq4w/11/

```
var library = {
  0942815367: {
    name: "Using SQLite",
    pub: "OReilly",
    year: 2010,
    rating: "3.9"
  },
  9238614075: {
    name: "HTML5 Canvas",
    pub: "OReilly",
    year: 2013,
    rating: "4.3"
  },
  4239867510: {
    name: "Essential GWT",
    pub: "Aw",
    year: 2011,
    rating: "2.6"
  }
},
inbasket = {
  6029738154: {
    name: "HTML5 Hacks",
    pub: "OReilly",
    year: 2012,
    rating: "4.5"
  },
  3901825674: {
    name: "Pro Django 2e",
    pub: "Apress",
    year: 2013,
    rating: "4.0"
  },
  4381529067: {
    name: "GWT in Action",
    pub: "Manning",
    year: 2007,
    rating: "3.7"
  },
  3014972685: {
    name: "Learning Node",
    pub: "OReilly",
    year: 2012,
    rating: "3.5"
  }
};

var result = _.cloneDeep(library);

for(var bookKey in inbasket) {
    if(Number(inbasket[bookKey]['rating']) > 3.9) {
      result[bookKey] = inbasket[bookKey];
    }
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 
JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for you input.